# SQL: Set time column to start from a specified time

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

How can I set a Column of a Data Type (time) to start from 8:00 A.M?. Since the default data type starts from midnight.

Is there a way to create a constraint to set the time to start from 8:00 AM and check whether the inserted time is 8:00 A.M or not ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_time CHECK(time > '08:00:00' )
```

You might want to add a `time < value` constraint as well so you have an upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

The time doesn't 'start' or 'end' anywhere, it's a single value. Do you mean that the column should only be allowed to hold values between 08h00 and 18h00 (or whatever)? If so, look into CHECK constraints.

You also need to consider what happens when someone INSERTs or UPDATEs a value that your constraint doesn't allow; you'll get an error, which you can then catch and handle appropriately in your application (or possibly stored procedure).

Alternatively, use an INSTEAD OF trigger (preferably in addition to the CHECK constraint) to change any invalid values to valid ones.

The best combination of CHECK constraint, trigger, stored procedure and application logic depends on your application architecture.